# Convert WindowsIdentity to ClaimsIdentity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, aspnetboilerplate

I have a web application and I need to use there AD UserGroups. I need to do this in my views and conntrollers:

```
var User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
if (User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\group"))
{
                Show();            
}
```

I´m using ClaimsBased Identity in application, but I have access to WindowsIndetity too. What I want is add WindowsIdentity claims / groups to ClaimIdentity and after that work with ActiveDirectory userGroups like roles.

It is possible ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: How do you login your users?

Comment: I´m using https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth

Answer (score 0):

I would not convert but rather authenticate the Windows Identity throught the Identity.SignInManager.

So, the SignInManager is using the AuthenticationType **Identity.Application** and provides you a `CreateUserPrincipalAsync` method to return the ClaimsPrincipal.

Once you do `SignInManager.SignInAsync` (or `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`) another Identity is created in the `HttpContext.User.Identities` - The `ClaimsIdentity` so far

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with was to use a GenericPrinciple.

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var principal = new GenericPrinciple(identity, new string[] {"roleA", "roleB"});
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

You can construct the array of roles from the groups in Active Directory.